# Passing session variables to JS

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass the `value userSession(id of the user)` to the javascript. But i can't seem to pass the session id to `var master`. I am a new to javascript here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#token-btn').hide();
        infoBox.onDisplay = function(ln){
           var master = "<?php echo $_SESSION['userSession']; ?>";
        if(ln.id == master)
            $('#token-btn')[0].style.display = "none";
        else
            $('#token-btn')[0].style.display = "";

        };
    });
```

## main.php

```
    <?php
        $id = $_SESSION['userSession'];
    ?>
    <li><a id="token-btn" href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Give Invitation Token</a>    </li>
```

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(master)` ?

Comment: <?php echo $_SESSION['userSession']; ?>

Comment: My guess is that you put `<php ?>` php tags inside a Javascript (.js) file, which does not work. See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

My earlier answer was wrong, so I have removed it.
Your php code is not getting parsed, so check your file extension. You are probably trying this on a .js file like @pete has commented.